# sshfs hangs linux server

Tags: linux-kernel, sshfs

My linux system uses java base application and it reads config file from remote server using sshfs and fuse. My system got hang in case of remote server does not response. 
linux kernel version 2.6.18-194.el5
SSHFS version 2.1
FUSE library version: 2.7.4
fusermount version: 2.7.4
using FUSE kernel interface version 7.8

Please help me to resolve this issue

Answer (score 0):

That's what SSHFS does. It tends to get stuck when server suddenly disappears or underlying ssh process dies. If sshfs is stuck (for the aforementioned reasons) and you're trying to access files over it, your processes will get stuck too. Consider rewriting your java application to use user-space ssh access methods and avoid using SSHFS/Fuse.

One popular ssh access library for java is this one:

http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/

Here's an example on how to get files from the remote server:

http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/ScpFrom.java.html